# Problem in communicating using Socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, communication

I'm hoping I haven't missed something stupid.  I am working on an application that communicates between a number of hand-held window's mobile computers and a central server.  The current architecture only allows short messages (up to 4096 bytes), I am modifying the application to allow larger communications when necessary.  This code seems to work intermittently, depending on the server's speed and the network communication speed.  I need to find a way make the server's receiving code more solid.  It occasionally works perfectly, other times the hand-held throws the error "Unable to write data to the transport connection.  An existing connection was forcible closed by the remote host."

Hand-held transmitting code:

```
public bool SendMessage(NetworkStream ansStream, string asMessage)  
{  
    try  
    {  
        Byte[] wBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asMessage.ToCharArray());  
        ansStream.Write(wBytes, 0, wBytes.Length);  
        return true;  
    }  
    catch (Exception E)  
    {  
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "Network Error");  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

Server side receiving code:

```
public const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 4096;  
public void ProcessMessage(object aClient)  
{  
    TcpClient wClient = (aClient as TcpClient);  
    try  
    {  
        byte[] wBytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];  
        StringBuilder wMessage = new StringBuilder();  
        using (NetworkStream wNetStream = wClient.GetStream())  
        {  
            try  
            {  
                int wiRead = 0;  
                int wiTotalBytes = 0;  
                do  
                {  
                    wiRead = wNetStream.Read(wBytes, 0, wBytes.Length);  
                    wMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wBytes, 0, wiRead));  
                    wiTotalBytes += wiRead;  

                    // my attempt to ensure entire message is read  
                    if (wNetStream.DataAvailable)  
                    {  
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);  
                    }  

                } while (wNetStream.DataAvailable);  

                if (wiTotalBytes > 0)  
                {  
                    string wsAnswerFile = "";  
                    string wsResult = DoBusinessProcess(wMessage.ToString(), out wsAnswerFile);  
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wsAnswerFile))  
                    {  
                        wBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(wsResult);  
                        wNetStream.Write(wBytes, 0, wBytes.Length);  
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        if (File.Exists(wsAnswerFile))  
                        {  
                            SendFile(wsAnswerFile, wNetStream);  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
            catch (Exception E)  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "Network Error");  
            }  
            finally  
            {  
                if (wNetStream != null)  
                {  
                    wNetStream.Close();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Network errors are common, you have to code to survive them... Are you opening and closing a socket each time you want to send a message? Otherwise I don't know how you identify message boundaries. On the other hand, is a bit strange you have a ProcessMessage method but the implementation is still working with the Stream...

Comment: Yes, I left that part out.  The client is declared in a loop that opens listener and sends the client off to a new thread.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I may come back to this approach later, but I've re-architected the client side to send the data in small messages as opposed to sending the entire file in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling ProcessMessage and passing it a TCPClient, how are you initializing those TCPCLient connections? If you are doing it in a loop without multithreading then you may get results like the ones you've explained. Of course I can't be sure without knowing how you have your client listening loop setup.

Check out this link: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server
 The second code snippet shows a listener loop that will start a new thread for each client. If you don't start a new thread for each client, if a new one is trying to connect while you are receiving data from the other one, it will say the server can't respond.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, the TcpClient is initialized in a loop that is creating a new thread for each connection.  Thank you for the link to that example, I'll be modifying my code to use the 'read until 0 bytes received' model.  That would match the MSDN answer I've found googling on my own.

Comment: I've tried both the do ... while (DataAvailable) method and the read until 0 bytes method and the do ... while is the method that works.  The problem is for the longer communications, the loop works reliable with the Thread.Sleep(1000) line, I'd like to be able to read all the contents without the Sleep, which slows down the response for shorter requests.  Any thoughts on what I am missing?